# RSS Feed parse showing error after :

Tags: php

This is a strange one for me, i am parsing an rss feed using simplexml_load_file, it's working fine up until:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$items = $xml->channel->item;
foreach($items as $offer)
{ 
    echo $offer->title;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $offer->guid;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $offer->description;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $offer->campinfo:amount;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $offer->campinfo:country;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $offer->campinfo:type;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<hr>";
?>
```

It hits these parts:

$offer->campinfo:amount; the "**:**" is causing the script to error out, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

I cannot find any information on this, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: example added

```
<item>
<title>win iPhone 6s!</title>
<link>http://qckclk.com/offer.php?id=341201&amp;pub=240627&amp;subid=</link>
<guid>http://qckclk.com/offer.php?id=341201&amp;pub=240627</guid>
<description>il suffit d&#039;;entrer votre numÃ©ro pour gagner 6s iPhone!</description>
<campinfo:amount>10.24</campinfo:amount>
<campinfo:campid>341201</campinfo:campid>
<campinfo:country>LU</campinfo:country>
<campinfo:type>Pin+Submit</campinfo:type>
<campinfo:epc>1.01</campinfo:epc>
<campinfo:ratio>9</campinfo:ratio>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:` is not valid in a variable name. If you need to access a property that isn't a valid identifier, you need to use `{"string"}` notation:

```
echo $offer->{"campinfo:amount"};
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores
>   As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

echo $offer->campinfo:amount;

contains `:` in the variable, which isnt legal according to the manual.

Change that or `var_dump ($offer)` to see whats actually in there

Comment: Just added an example of the original rss.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing to know in future the answer was:

$offer->children('campinfo', true)->amount;